# Do forests create wind?

Tags: air, climate-science, meteorology

Forests evapotranspire more water vapor into air than surrounding areas, have more clouds, and are usually cooler (because of evaporative cooling). How does this affect the air pressure of forests? Lets say there is no external winds, would a forest create wind blowing towards it, or away from it?

Comment: https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/a32935704/forests-generate-wind-theory-science-argument/

Comment: https://interestingengineering.com/theory-claims-that-forests-not-only-create-rain-but-also-wind

Answer (score 4):

Trees releasing moisture into the air will have a cooling effect on the air. If the forest is large enough, this may cause a temperature (and pressure) difference between the air above it, and above a dryer region of land nearby. Winds can then flow from the air above the forest to these dryer areas.

It is known that if there are large temperature differences between the air above dry land and the air above the sea, we get the formation of high and low pressure systems, which then give rise to local winds.

To answer your question, a large forest releasing water into the air can cause pressure differences in the air leading to winds.

Comment: Is it higher or lower pressure inside a forest? Because air is cooler, and cooler air sinks, one might say higher pressure. But then the air is also more humid, and water vapor is lighter than air, so the air rises. So it might be lower pressure. Also if when a cloud condenses, it creates a low pressure system, it might suck up air from the forest below, and that would make the forest lower pressure.

Comment: Water enters the atmosphere via transpiration as you stated. And warm water vapor rises up into the atmosphere, and as it gets higher and higher, the cooler air of the atmosphere causes the water vapor to condense, creating clouds.  When a cloud condenses, the pressure actually becomes higher, not lower.